# SED deletes one more line than it should do

Tags: sed

Here you are the snippet:

https://bitbucket.org/sedjs/workspace/snippets/k7enjL

I try to delete all lines between two patterns but SED deletes one more line than expected.

Any idea how to improve the behavior?

Rgs,
Ziggi

SED should only delete lines between patterns provided but it removes one more line, the one having same closing pattern but of different opening pattern.

Comment: Just use one less remove line instruction.

Comment: Please do not post links to external lines. Please all the stuff into the question as text with `formatting`.

Comment: `how to improve the behavior?` The behavior work correctly. Do not use `//,//` range of addresses if you want to remove a single line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
'/^INSERT INTO `medicover`\.`active_record_change_log`.*;$/d'
```

This will delete lines starting `INSERT INTO medicover\.active_record_change_log` and ending in `;`.

N.B. Formatting for SO does not allow for backticks to be represented inline so the the above literal is miss them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that SED implements the range matching as follows:

- line 1 matches with the starting range regex
- line 2 matches with the ending range regex --> delete both lines

And it repeats the process, thus deleting lines 1 to 8 in pairs.

Then it reaches line 9, which matches the starting range regex, and it applies the same logic for line 10 : it matches the ending range regex, so both lines are getting deleted.

You can test the validity of that assumption by commenting out or deleting one of your lines containing "active_record_change" so that you are left with an even number of those lines. All of them will get deleted in pairs, and line 11 will show up in the output.

Why don't you just simply delete all lines containing "active_record_change_log" instead of resorting to range matching?

Answer (score -1):

```
pattern_start="start"
pattern_end="end"

# Delete lines between the patterns

sed "/$pattern_start/,/$pattern_end/{/$pattern_start/b;/$pattern_end/!d}" input.txt
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?